# warning about "DR102 too much data written uncommitted"

Tags: mongodb, batch-processing

Find some similar questions but different to us... 
Hope anybody here have seen the following:

Two weeks ago, we released a java batch to update/insert data to mongo, 
then 2,3 days ago, the following annoying warning comes:

```
 Primary
  [connXXXX] warning: DR102 too much data written uncommitted 314.577MB
 Secondary
  [rsSync] warning: DR102 too much data written uncommitted 314.577MB
  [rsSync] warning: DR102 too much data written uncommitted 314.581MB
  [rsSync] warning: DR102 too much data written uncommitted 314.585MB
```

We thought it is because the speed of batch, so we changed the batch to one thread
and make it much slower. However, waited for several minutes, the same warning happened again...

After that, we found the following tickets which are fixing similar problems.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6925
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6816

But our mongo version is different to them, so I am wondering 
if they are same bug and whether they can be fixed by version up?

```
----- Our Spec ---------------
・MongoDB (version 2.0.4)
・1 Primary, 1 Secondary, 1 Arbiter
・One insert/update 1KB～20KB
・Batch access at peak 10~20
------------------------------
```

Anyway, I also appreciate any info related to this.

Comment: their fix versions were after yours so I would try and upgrade

Comment: Thanks for replying. As that version is running in production environment and hard to version up, we finally decided to change the batch.

Comment: I also noticed that Asya mentioned that those tickets were not connected to your problem so might be good to follow with the group thread if you haven't

Comment: Thanks, Sammaye. I replied in that group. I thought my post wasn't passing the check because I couldn't check my post after posting immediately... Anyway, I think my problem is very similar to 6816. In our problem, we are updating/inserting too fast to primary, so by some reason, the sycn to secondary because heavy and the warning comes out. So I am going to try slow down my batch to check whether the same problem will happen or not.